# Search for file title and rename file accordingly

Tags: batch-file, rename

We have several files with random file names.  For each file we have to open it using Notepad and go to line 1 which contains the Report Title for example "PAST DUE REPORT 1." Then close and rename the file to PAST DUE REPORT 1.  This is too time consuming and would like to know if a batch script can help automate this process.

For example:

In "C:\FILES" I have FILE1, FILE2 and FILE3.  These files are not in any format specific so the batch script must search for all file format.

If keyword "PAST DUE REPORT 1" exist on line 1 then rename the file to "PAST DUE REPORT 1" and move it to "C:\REPORTS". Repeat until each file is renamed and moved.

I'm also open to other suggestions.

------ edited ------

Here is an actual example of one of the files.

```
NOTICE OF PAST DUE PAYMENT on MM/DD/YYYY for Account 123 Loan 0005

Your auto loan 2010 Toyota Sienna payment due on MM/DD/YY is 14 days past due. The standard payment is $200.00.  The total past due is $200.00. The late charge is $15.00.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know, what's in your first line, but maybe the batch could look like this:

```
for %%F in (C:\FILES\*.*) do call :renamefile "%%~fF"
exit
:renamefile {String} file
set /p "firstLine=<%~1"
echo/%firstLine%|findstr /i /c:"PAST DUE REPORT"||exit/B
::Without knowing more about the first line, I can't set the correct name
set "newName=%firstLine%"
ren %1 "%newName%"
move "%~dp1%newName%" "C:\REPORTS"
```

maybe also this function I often use in my own projects could help:

```
:createUniqueName {String} file
set "return=%~f1"
if not exist "%~f1" exit /B 0
set /a i=0
:_createUniqueName
set /a i+=1
set "return=%~dpn1 (%i%)%~x1"
if exist "%return%" goto _createUniqueName
exit /b %i%
```

Comment: The first part of the script may work.  What information do you need from the first line?  Here is a sample of the verbiage from the first line.

Comment: NOTICE OF PAST DUE PAYMENT on MM/DD/YYYY for Account 123 Loan 0005

Comment: So in this example, what should be the filename?

Comment: It should be "NOTICE OF PAST DUE PAYMENT" or it can be hard code it to something short such as "PAST DUE NOTICE".

Comment: I don't really understand this... the filename has to be unique (do you want to numerate all "past due notice"s? Or is this different every time and you want to have the first 5 words or all words before the "on <date>"?)

Comment: Timlg07 Thanks for all your help. I’ve hired a coder from freelancer and it has been completed.

Comment: Ok, good to know. But please include more information in your next questions, like possible inputs and the expected output (and maybe possible patterns to achieve that output).